# Transfer values from one stack to another keeping the same order in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, stack

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 1000;
class Stack
{
    int top=-1;
    int arr[MAX];

public:

    void push(int value)
    {
        if (top > MAX - 1)
            cout << "Stack Overflow";
        else
             arr[top++] = value;

    }

    int pop()
    {
        if (top == -1)
            cout << "Stack Underflow";
        else
            return arr[top--];

    }


    void StackTransfer(stack <int> &s1, stack <int> &s2)
    {
        int x;
        if (s1.empty())
            return;

        x = s1.top();
        s1.pop();
        StackTransfer(s1, s2);
        s2.push(x);



    }
};


int main()
{
    stack <int> st1, st2, st3;
    st1.push(10);
    st1.push(20);
    st2.push(30);
    st2.push(40);
    cout<<st3.StackTransfer(&st1, &st2);


}
```

I want to transfer values, but when I call StackTransfer() function in main (), I am getting this error

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0135   class "std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator>>" has no member "StackTransfer"*

Is the logic of StackTransfer() correct for transferring values and preserving the order same?

Comment: Use a third stack?

Comment: Voting to reopen as the post has been substantially expanded in the 4th revision (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68885110/4) with important context added.

Answer (score 0):

You made several mistakes in your code.

The first one is mismatching the class names: you declare an ordinary class `Stack` and then you use a templated class `stack<int>`. Those are two unrelated classes and the compiler is absolutely right when it complains the `stack<int>` class does not have a `StackTransfer` method.

The second mistake is a way you try to call the method. Either the method acts on an object and then:

(a) there's only one explicit parameter to it (another one is `this`),
(b) its name should indicate a direction of the action: `void StackTransferFrom(Stack &s)` or `void StackTransferTo(Stack &s)`,
(c) the parameter should be the same class (`Stack`, not `stack<int>`), and
(d) it will be called on some object of the declared class: `Stack s1, s2; ....; s1.StackTransferFrom(s2);`

or the method acts on two objects and then:

(a) it should be defined as `static`, and
(b) it will be called with two arguments: `Stack::StackTransfer(s1, s2);` without any third object, but
(c) with a class identifier.

Another one is using the ampersand operator `&` when calling the function. Your method has reference-type parameters, not pointers, so you should call it with references to variables: `StackTransfer(s1, s2)` not with pointers to them: `StackTransfer(&s1, &s2)`. The latter would work with a static void `StackTransferTo(Stack *s1, Stack *s2)` method.

Your attempt to send the result to standard output is wrong, too – your function is declared `void`, which means it returns no value, hence you get nothing from it that could be output to `cout`.

Yet another mistake lurks in the `push()` method: you used a post-increment operator there, but the initial value of `top` is minus-one. As a result the first value `push`-ed to your stack will be written to `arr[-1]`, **before** the array's beginning. This triggers Undefined Behavior of your program.

Improved version:

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    const int MAX = 1000;
    class Stack
    {
        int top = -1;
        int arr[MAX];
    
    public:
    
        void push(int value)
        {
            if (top >= MAX - 1)
                std.cout << "Stack Overflow\n";
            else
                arr[++top] = value;
        }
    
        int pop()
        {
            if (top < 0)
                std.cout << "Stack Underflow\n";
            else
                return arr[top--];
        }

        bool empty()
        {
            return top == -1;
        }

        int top()
        {
            if (empty())
            {
                std.cout << "Stack is empty\n";
                return 0;
            }
            return arr[top];
        }
    
        void StackTransfer(Stack &source)
        {
            if (source.empty())
                return;
    
            int x = source.top();
            source.pop();
            StackTransfer(source);
            push(x);
        }
    };
    
    
    int main()
    {
        Stack st1, st2;
        st1.push(10);
        st1.push(20);
        st2.push(30);
        st2.push(40);
        
        st2.StackTransfer(st1);
    }
```